# How to make a COUNT of items that can appear in two different tables with a GROUP BY per day?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I have a SQL query that tells me how many people have logged in at least once in the past day and I would like to make a query to know how many people have logged in at least once or read an email in the past year for each language (`Lang`).

For example with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
    (`App Type` varchar(11), `Lang` varchar(2), `Session ID` int, `session_time` datetime, `User ID` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO sessions
    (`App Type`, `Lang`, `Session ID`, `session_time`, `User ID`)
VALUES
    #july 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-07-29 00:00:00', 1193745),
    # june 2021
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2021-06-29 00:00:00', 12345),
    # june 2020
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960339, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1292997),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960407, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1055040),
    ('pwa_android', 'fr', 46960412, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 1120109),
    ('browser', 'fr', 46960391, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 955480),
    ('pwa_android', 'en', 46960389, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 800169),
    ('browser', 'es', 46960353, '2020-06-29 00:00:00', 54321)

;


CREATE TABLE unique_open_emails
    (`date` datetime, `lang` varchar(2), `user_id` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO unique_open_emails
    (`date`, `lang`, `user_id`)
VALUES
    ('2016-04-12 00:00:00', 'fr', 115434),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11357),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 137481),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10296),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 125772),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 955480),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9269),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90716),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 26330),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89072),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 87416),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88358),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 102515),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89867),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 119146),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 133316),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90095),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16510),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 21530),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 81581),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'es', 54321),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 29363),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90326),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 23961),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89000),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9484),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11845),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 41231),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 588),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16678),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 19674),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130113),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 84719),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 123252),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 4676),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 113636),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17452),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136544),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15917),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 82787),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 81620),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 135298),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15643),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 80981),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 51827),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90554),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10277),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 24432),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 6651),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 64106),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 119080),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 72659),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130004),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 22320),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136966),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11317),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 79031),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 90800),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16149),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 61463),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 5383),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 87674),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10223),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88100),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91691),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89423),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 126),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 86858),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 1419),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89849),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 15721),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 86444),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 130822),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 73991),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 113969),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16779),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 71267),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 61067),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89081),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 24815),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91928),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 13071),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 1942),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 44012),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 52049),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 6626),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 7034),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 20442),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 75422),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 16673),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17325),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 7898),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 85226),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136557),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 134423),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 68723),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'en', 118331),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91298),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136046),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 136891),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 9169),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 88946),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 115919),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 44492),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 89783),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 137482),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 10072),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 38636),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 11227),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 108310),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 4700),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 17976),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 8580),
    ('2016-04-13 00:00:00', 'fr', 91316)
;
```

I tried:

```
SELECT sessions.session_time, `Lang`, (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`USER ID`))
  FROM sessions s2 JOIN unique_open_emails u ON s2.`User ID`=u.user_id
  WHERE (s2.session_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(sessions.session_time, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND sessions.session_time)
  OR (u.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(u.date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND u.date)
) AS alive_users
FROM sessions
GROUP BY sessions.session_time, sessions.Lang
```

But it returns:

```
session_time            Lang    alive_users
2020-06-29T00:00:00Z    en     0   
2020-06-29T00:00:00Z    es     0
2020-06-29T00:00:00Z    fr     0
2021-06-29T00:00:00Z    en     0
2021-06-29T00:00:00Z    es     0
2021-06-29T00:00:00Z    fr     0
2021-07-29T00:00:00Z    en     0
2021-07-29T00:00:00Z    es     0
2021-07-29T00:00:00Z    fr     0
```

So not only the dates are missing but also the numbers are wrong.

You can test it in [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/708ad8/5/0).

I use MySQL 5.7

Also, the real data is 37 million lines for the unique_open_emails table only so the query will never finish. I don't know if the query is not optimized (indexes and stuff), so if a script will go faster.

I think I am missing the 2016 dates because I am not selecting them in the query, only selecting the dates from the sessions table. Do you know how I can include the 2016?

Comment: Your fiddle is not reachable.

Comment: *But it returns:* Provide desired output for shown data. PS. Readable fiddle with provided data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0ff772fdb190592ce403ea2850fccbc1

Comment: Please explain your data.  Why are you giving an example *by day* if your question is *by year*?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to make a query to know how many people have logged in at least once or read an email in the past year for each language (Lang).

I think you want `union all` and `group by`:

```
select lang, count(distinct user_id)
from ((select user_id, lang
       from sessions
       where session_time > now() - interval 1 year
      ) union all
      (select user_id, lang
       from unique_open_emails
       where date > now() - interval 1 year
      )
     ) u
group by lang;
```

Comment: Many thanks! Do you know how I can do it backward? I mean calculate and insert in a table how many people have logged in at least once or read an email in the past year for all days in the tables?